# login to WordPress with phone number instead of username

Tags: wordpress, authentication, mobile, plugins

I intend to write a WordPress plugin that enable users to log in using mobile phone number and password instead of username. The first time the user will register with phone number and password and the plugin will send a confirmation code to them, and after that the user will login using the phone number and password. Can I use phone number instead of username by preventing the user from entering any characters other than numbers in the WordPress registeration form? and is this the best way to do that?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not natively supported by Wordpress, but there are existing plugins that use this kind of feature like: https://wordpress.org/plugins/login-with-phone-number/

You can use this for reference when developing your own plugin.

To restrict to only number entries you can use HTML5 input type number:

```
<input type="number" name="phoneid" />
```

For this to work you need to use a browser that can handle HTML5 and include this doctype in your HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: I see, Thank you very much, meinert.

Comment: Thank you, also ,the free plugin you mentioned here added the type="number" to the inputs.